# How to send data from one controller to other in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How to send the json data from FirstCtrl to secondCtrl using angularjs.

Can anyone please help me out regarding this ...

First.js:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {

    //firstCtrl json data
       $.getJSON("sample.json", function (json) {
            console.log(json);
         });
    });
```

Second.js:

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('secondCtrl', function ($scope) {

       //get the firstCtrl json data here
    });
```

Comment: duplicate for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434126/how-to-share-data-between-two-controllers-in-angularjs?rq=1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would also suggest a service that gets and returns data from and to the controllers.

we create the two controllers and then we create a service with two functions:
1. one to get the json data
2. one to return the json data

Like so:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('FirstCtrl', function( $scope, myService ){
 //we create or get the json object
 $scope.myjsonObj = {
      'animal':'cat',
      'feed':'frieskies',
      'color':'white',
      'sex':'male'
      };

      //pass the json object to the service
      myService.setJson($scope.myjsonObj);
})

.controller('SecondCtrl', function( $scope, myService ){
        //call service getJson() function to get the data
       $scope.myreturnedData = myService.getJson();
})
 .factory('myService', function(){
    var myjsonObj = null;//the object to hold our data
     return {
     getJson:function(){
       return myjsonObj;
     },
     setJson:function(value){
      myjsonObj = value;
     }
     }

});
```

and the HTML partial would be:

```
 <div ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
          {{myjsonObj}}
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
            {{myreturnedData.animal}}
            {{myreturnedData.feed}}
            {{myreturnedData.color}}
            {{myreturnedData.sex}}
        </div>
```

Hope helps, good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot for ur help.What for factory is used ? can u please explain me

Comment: You can use services/factory (almost the same functionality) , to share values accross your web-app.
Please for more ,read this documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Comment: hello, please ask a new question for your new problem with an example to examine it from the start.

Answer (score 1):

If the second controller is nested you can use $parent to access the scope of the first controller. You would need to assign the value of json to $scope such as

```
$scope.json = my_json
```

Then in the second controller you can say

```
$scope.json = $scope.$parent.json;
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
 
 app.controller('Ctrl1', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
 $scope.msg = 'World';
 $rootScope.name = 'AngularJS';
 });
 
 app.controller('Ctrl2', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
 $scope.msg = 'Dot Net Tricks';
 $scope.myName = $rootScope.name;
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="Ctrl1" style="border:2px solid blue; padding:5px">
 Hello {{msg}}!
 <br />
 Hello {{name}}!
 (rootScope)
</div>
<br />
<div ng-controller="Ctrl2" style="border:2px solid green; padding:5px">
 Hello {{msg}}!
 <br />
 Hey {{myName}}!
 <br />
 Hi {{name}}! (rootScope)
</div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I would not advise playing with `$rootScope`, only if as a case in point.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can simply make a new **service** with two functions one to save the date and one to give them, this service then can be accessed from any where.
In addition, you can assign the data to a `$rootScope.someVar` for example, and in this way too you can retrieve the data from any where

Answer (score 0):

Just use `$rootScope` to achieve this. 
 In your first controller assign `$rootScope.json = $scope.json;` and It will available on the entire application. So, you can access `$rootScope.json` wherever you want on that particular app