# Passing Object from One Controller to Another AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I need to pass an object from one controller to another and have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35407661) solution but it is not working.

Here the code:

```
angular.module("customerApp", [])
.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, myService, $http, $location) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.pinFormCheck = function () {
        vm.count++;
        if (vm.pinForm.$valid && vm.details.PIN === vm.pin && vm.count <= 2) {
            location.href = "http://localhost:51701/Home/MainMenu";
            $scope.obj = {
                'cid': 'vm.details.CID',
                'name': 'vm.details.Name',
                'pin': 'vm.details.PIN',
                'bal': 'vm.details.Bal',
                'status': 'vm.details.cardStatus'

            };
            console.log(vm.details.Bal);//the correct balance get displayed in console
        } else {
            vm.failPin = true;
        }
    };
})

.controller('CheckCtrl', function ($scope, myService) {
    $scope.data = myService.getObj();
})

.factory('myService', function () {
    var obj = null;
    return {
        getObj: function () {
            return obj;
        },
        setObj: function (value) {
            obj = value;
        }
    }
});
```

Here is the view from which the first object is passed:

```
<body ng-app="customerApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
        <form name="vm.pinForm">
            <input type="password" ng-model="vm.pin" ng-required="true" />
            <p><button ng-disabled="vm.count >=3" ng-click="vm.pinFormCheck();" ng-init="vm.count=0">Proceed</button></p>
                    </form>
                    ...
```

Here' the second view where I need the object

```
<html ng-app="customerApp">
    <body ng-controller="CheckCtrl">
        <div>
            <h1>your balance is {{data.bal}}</h1>
            ....
```

The balance from `vm.details.Bal` from the first view must appear in `data.bal` in the second view, but nothing is appearing.

Comment: Service data doesn't persist between page loads. Consider using [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or creating an [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) with a router such as [ngRoute](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ngroute/info) or [UI Router](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular-ui-router/info).

Answer (score 0):

You can just save vm.details in some factory.
And then get it in `CheckCtrl` from this factory.
Factories in AngularJS implement singleton pattern. So saved data will be kept in until your app exists.

You tried to do next thing `myService.getObj();` But you didn't save anything to the service.

Inject `myService` to the `MainCtrl` and then save details into it.